# How to profile a dynamically linked library without sprof?

Tags: c++, profiling, dynamic-linking, shared-libraries, sprof

I am having [some trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334688/segfault-with-sprof-good-without) profiling a dynamic library, and I can't seem to find anybody who has used sprof.

Does anybody know of an alternative tool that can give a call graph for a dynamically linked library?

Comment: [*Maybe this will help?*](http://greg-n-blog.blogspot.com/2010/01/profiling-shared-library-on-linux-using.html)

Comment: You can use any modern tool, like: valgrind (with callgrind subtool), gperftools (pprof, cpuprofiler), perf (part of linux kernel, perf.wiki.kernel.org/), oprofile. Any of them should provide call graph.

Comment: As an additional note, gprof is [unable to profile calls to shared libraries](http://gernotklingler.com/blog/gprof-valgrind-gperftools-evaluation-tools-application-level-cpu-profiling-linux/#conclusion-and-comparison). Apparently gprof combines the samples collected for a shared library function with the samples collected for its caller, so that only the cumulative stats of both are reported, but not individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use valgrind and [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)